# LEFT JOIN not return right value

Tags: join, query

I am trying to join 3 tables with it foreign keys, but for some reason one of the return value from the query doesn't return correct when I use `LEFT JOIN` for the 3 tables but I removed the one that didn't return correct and tried to query it separately it does below is the query for the 3 tables with `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT ROUND(COUNT(CASE WHEN patient_registration.payment_status = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)*500/2) AS current_balance, 
       COUNT(CASE WHEN patient_registration.payment_status = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS patient_subscribed, 
       COUNT(CASE WHEN patient_registration.payment_status = 0 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS patient_unsubscribed 
FROM hospital_information 
LEFT JOIN patient_registration ON patient_registration.hospital_id = hospital_information.id 
WHERE hospital_information.id = 3
```

According to the above I get the correct return for `current_balance = 1000`,`patient_subscribed = 2` and `patient_unsubsribed = 21` but when I tried to add another `LEFT JOIN` I get wrong return, see below:

```
SELECT ROUND(COUNT(CASE WHEN patient_registration.payment_status = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)*500/2) AS current_balance,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN patient_registration.payment_status = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS patient_subscribed, 
       COUNT(CASE WHEN patient_registration.payment_status = 0 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS patient_unsubscribed,
       SUM(payment.price) AS total_generated 
FROM hospital_information 
LEFT JOIN payment ON hospital_information.id = payment.hospital_id
LEFT JOIN patient_registration ON hospital_information.id = patient_registration.hospital_id 
WHERE hospital_information.id = 3
```

I get wrong response as

| current_balance | patient_subscribed | patient_unsubsribed | total_generated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 4 | 42 | 23000 |

instead of `total_generated = 1000` but when I tried it seperated as below I got the right answer:

```
SELECT SUM(payment.price) AS total_generated 
FROM hospital_information 
LEFT JOIN payment ON hospital_information.id = payment.hospital_id WHERE hospital_information.id = 3
```

Comment: Clearly there are multiple `patient_registration` per row of the other tables. You need to pre-aggregate it. Sample data would help

Comment: The biggest help here would be if you provided example rows for each Table so we can see what the data looks like before you `JOIN` the Tables together. As Charlieface points out, you likely have a misunderstanding on the cardinality of your Tables and how they relate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this but LEFT JOIN the SELECT statement separately as below:

```
SELECT 
* 
FROM(SELECT ROUND(COUNT(CASE WHEN patient_registration.payment_status = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)*500/2) AS current_balance,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN patient_registration.payment_status = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS patient_subscribed,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN patient_registration.payment_status = 0 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS patient_unsubscribed,hospital_information.hospital_name
    FROM hospital_information 
    LEFT JOIN patient_registration ON patient_registration.hospital_id = hospital_information.id
    WHERE hospital_information.id = 3 GROUP BY hospital_information.id) t1 
    INNER JOIN
    (SELECT
    SUM(payment.price)/2 AS total_generated,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(CURDATE()) = MONTH(payment.created_at) Then payment.price Else 0 End)/2 as current_month
    FROM hospital_information 
    LEFT JOIN payment ON hospital_information.id = payment.hospital_id WHERE hospital_information.id = 3 GROUP BY hospital_information.id) t2
```